# Javascript node.js, set cookies to be used on another page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cookies, path

I have a node.js site. On page 1 there is `textBox 1`. On page 2 I'd like to retrieve the user input from `textBox 1` and use its value. Page 1 and 2 are not related, like there's no button on page1 that will bring up page 2, so I can't use URL to store values.

Now I'd like to set up a cookie on page1 and read it on page two by using  `document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";`. How should I specify the path?

This is how I get page2 in Node.js

```
app.get('/page2', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public'+ '/page2.html'));
   console.log(" in auth code");

});
```

But the actual url when page2 opens up is something like `https://localhost:8080/page2?result=38tuts`, as it will receive a http redirect as a response of a xmlhttprequest. Or is there another way of passing page1 value to Page2?

Comment: I believe path is an optional parameter when creating a cookie. Have you tried leaving it off?

Comment: yea it's optional but the default path is current page i think

Comment: if the domain name of where you created the cookie persists, then so should the cookie. The way you reach page 2 shouldn't matter, any page on the site can retrieve the value of the created cookie at any time.

Comment: You are right man!! If you wanna move your comments to an answer i'd accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, thank you. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

path is an optional parameter that can be left off in this case. If the domain name of where you created the cookie persists, then so should the cookie. The way you reach page 2 shouldn't matter, any page on the site can retrieve the value of the created cookie at any time.